# How to downloadable app for older versions of iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, app-store, upgrade

I'm sorry if my question is stupid.
My first app was just published on app store and already two users can't download the app because their iphone isn't upgraded to iOS. 6.1.

I developed the app for each iphone (display retina and other), but i haven't considered the version of iOS.

How can i do to resolve this problem?

I would like that every user could download the app, even those who have an old version of iOS.

Comment: Have you used any iOS 6 specific capabilities/class methods, or would your app work as-is if you targeted iOS 5 within Xcode?

Comment: @middaparka I developed for iOS6 but i don't think that there are any class method specific for iOS6. Can i test the app with iphone simulator and an older version of iOS?

i know that in "project" -> info tab there is a menù with iOS deployment target. Maybe can help me that menù ?

Comment: @ManuelRagazzini, try lowering your app deployment target to iOS 5 and the test your app before sending an update to App Store just to make sure lowering the target deployment does not cause any thing else. That should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not using any class that are part of IOS6 then you can upload a new build version 
(as your app is already live)with selecting lower iOS Deployment Target version while creating build.
But if you are using feature like Facebook/twitter of social framework then it will not work with lower IOS devices and you have to use other option for Facebook/twitter integration.

Other way is to upgrade your client device to IOS6.1 so they can download it easily.